# Migrate to AWS from Linode

Tags: amazon-web-services, database-connection, postgresql-9.1, linode

Migration to another server is not easy that way when having a large database, 
we want to move our database in linode to amazon RDS database, i tried to pg_dumb and pg_restore
and it success but it consume a lot of time

My Question is:
is there a fast way like compression 
OR
can i sync the database in linode with the database in Amazon RDS

so i just then need to change CNAME to refer to amazon and then it will continue work as we already sync the database together ?

Any suggestion would help !

Comment: Reposted here: http://serverfault.com/questions/559320/migrate-to-aws-from-linode . It's more appropriate for ServerFault. Please delete this question; don't repost to multiple StackExchange sites, especially without linking between them. It wastes everybody's time.

Comment: Ok, thanks i post here to get everyone help